# Find what Level an Element is in Tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, function-definition

So i've got this problem where I'm supposed to find the level of an element in a tree. Nothing seems to work out so im reaching out here for help.

This is what i've got so far. The problem here is that the 4th assert, where the returned level is supposed to be 2, doesnt work and the assert is alerted. I've thought of maybe trying to not do it recursivly, but how could that be done?

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, const int element) {

    int level = 0;

    if (tree == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (tree->data == element) {
        return level;
    }

    if (element < (tree)->data) {
        level++;
        findElementLevel(tree->left, element);
        return level;
    }

    if (element > (tree)->data) {
        level++;
        findElementLevel(tree->right, element);
        return level;
    }
}

void testNewTree(void) {

    BSTree tree = emptyTree();
    assert(isEmpty(tree));

    int arr[5] = {3,2,5,1,4}, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        insertSorted(&tree, arr[i]);
    }

    assert(findElementLevel(tree, 3) == 0);

    assert(findElementLevel(tree, 2) == 1);

    assert(findElementLevel(tree, 5) == 1);

    assert(findElementLevel(tree, 1) == 2);

    assert(findElementLevel(tree, 4) == 2);

}
```

Comment: `level` is a local variable. It will always be 0 or 1 when the top level function returns.

Comment: You reset the local variable `level` in each recursion. Perhaps it should be **`static`** `int level = 0;` and then you also need to decrement on return (so it works next time).

Comment: The level should begin being 0, but not reset when the function returns. But im out of ideas on how to fix it. Its not allowed for level to be a static nor global variable

Comment: Why is it not allowed?

Comment: It can be a parameter to the function.

Comment: Wrong by me. It is allowed for it to be a static variable, but cant be a parameter to the function. But even if its a static varible it doesnt seem to work

Comment: You have to increment it on arrival in the function, and decrement it on exit (having captured it). Otherwise the next time you try it will be wrong.

Comment: Do not use a `static` object for this; it is widely viewed as bad programming (and fails in threads). The [code by Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493883/298225) is suitable, although it can be tightened and prettied up somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

The function always starts from the declaration of the local variable level that is set to 0.

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, const int element) {

    int level = 0;
```

This value that is 0 (or 1 due to its increment in a current recursive function call) )is returned in case when the target element is found in any actual level

```
if (tree->data == element) {
    return level;
}
```

You have to accumulate levels.

A recursive function can be defined for example the following way

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, const int element) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else  if ( element < tree->data ) {
        int level = findElementLevel(tree->left, element);
        return level == -1 ? level : level + 1;
    }
    else if ( tree->data < element ) {
        int level = findElementLevel(tree->right, element);
        return level == -1 ? level : level + 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Pay attention to that the qualifier const for the second parameter does not make great sense because the function deals with a copy of the value of the supplied argument. The function can be declared just like

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, int element);
```

Comment: Im supposed to return on what level the element is in the tree. I also doesnt understand whats happening here "? level : ++level;"

Comment: @JohnJohn: If you replace `return level == -1 ? level : ++level;` by `return level < 0 ? -1 : level+1;`, it will do the same thing, and you may understand it better. The expression `a ? b : c` tests `a` and uses `b` if `a` is true and `c` if `a` is false. (This ternary operator `? :` can also be used to select the tree branch to explore and eliminate redundant code; we do not need separate clauses and calls for the left and right sides.)

Comment: @JohnJohn If a next recursive call returns -1 (that means that the element is not found) then it is returned further. Otherwise if it is found in a next call it is returned incremented.

Comment: @JohnJohn In fact this construction return level == -1 ? level : ++level; is equivalent to if ( level == -1 ) return level; else return ++level;

Comment: Alright, I think it all worked out now. Just gotta do some more testing before sending it in, thanks for all the help. Will reach out if more problems appears.

Answer (score 0):

This function is easier and shorter to write iteratively than recursively. The code is just:

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, const int element)
{
    for (int level = 0; tree; ++level)
    {
        if (tree->data == element)
            return level;
        tree = tree->data < element ? tree->left : tree->right;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

With explanation, it is:

```
int findElementLevel(const BSTree tree, const int element)
{
    /*  Use a loop to process each level.  We start counting levels at zero and
        increment on each iteration.  We continue as long as there is more of
        the tree to explore ("tree" evaluates as true, i.e., non-null), or jump
        out of the loop with a return if the target element is found.
    */
    for (int level = 0; tree; ++level)
    {
        //  If we found the target, return the level it is on.
        if (tree->data == element)
            return level;

        /*  Otherwise, descend to the left or the right according to which
            side the target element must be on.
        */
        tree = tree->data < element ? tree->left : tree->right;
    }

    /*  If we reached the end of the tree without finding the element, return
        -1.
    */
    return -1;
}
```